# A way to hold frequently changing values in memory

Tags: database, data-structures, solr, lucene, nosql

I am trying to build a real-time web service that deals with dynamic 10k spatial entries that keep changing every 15 seconds. **imagine moving vehicles** I only need to deal with the latest values. So I do not want to keep the old values in the database.

I want to use Sphinx or Lucene as a full-text search server over the values but I do not know how to "Hold" these changing values for 15 seconds.

**The Question:** 
Should I store the values in MongoDB , MySQL, XML, flat files, or is there a way to store them directly as objects in Memory and still able to manipulate them and update their values?

Thank you.

Comment: "store them directly as objects in Memory" if you want your entities to have "object nature", do look at Neo4j.

Comment: do you have to make spatial queries?

Comment: Yes, and this is what i am actually looking for now, trying to combine Sphinx or Solr with Redis. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you look at Redis:

> Redis is an open source, advanced key-value store. It is often
> referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings,
> hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets.
>
> You can run atomic operations on
> these types, like appending to a string; incrementing the value in a
> hash; pushing to a list; computing set intersection, union and
> difference; or getting the member with highest ranking in a sorted
> set.
>
> In order to achieve its outstanding performance, Redis works with
> an in-memory dataset. Depending on your use case, you can persist it
> either by dumping the dataset to disk every once in a while, or by
> appending each command to a log.

http://redis.io/topics/introduction

Answer (score 0):

You can use Solr near realtime capabilities combined with the spatial queries, if you don't need to persist the info you could use a in memory index. Depending on the expected number of queries per second and maximum response time you should dimension your hardware accordingly.

anyway, solr may be helpful if you need to make full text queries along with the spatial data, if not, mongodb support spatial queries out of the box and can be a more straightforward system.

Comment: Well, I need the Expire feature in Redis to set a timeout for keys in memory. Currently MongoDB does not have this feature, It's still under development, but there is a work around for doing this in MongoDB by using capped collections, So currently i am building a prototype for the service using MongoDB.